# Converting my SELECT query to a less complex one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good evening all,

I am currently working at a project of mine to get more skill and knowledge about SQL, but at this moment I am stuck at a head cracker. So far I spent over an hour just trying all different approaches, with only 1 working which is way too complex.

The query I have to create:
Select all the huurovereenkomsten (leases) which contains a accessoire with the name 'Kinderzitje'  OR 'Helm' AND contains at least 2 bikes.

```
    SELECT h.Huurovereenkomst_id, h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
      FROM Huurovereenkomst AS h
      WHERE h.Huurovereenkomst_id IN (
            SELECT h.Huurovereenkomst_id
            FROM Huurovereenkomst AS h
                JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets AS hf ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id
                JOIN Fiets AS f ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id
            GROUP BY h.Huurovereenkomst_id,h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
            HAVING COUNT(hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id) >= 2
            )
        AND h.Huurovereenkomst_id IN (
            SELECT h.Huurovereenkomst_id
            FROM Huurovereenkomst AS h
            JOIN HuurovereenkomstAccessoire as ha ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Huurovereenkomst_id
            JOIN Accessoire as a ON ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Accessoire_id = a.Accessoire_id
            JOIN AccessoireSoort AS aso ON a.Accessoire_Soortnr = aso.AccessoireSoort_id
            WHERE aso.AccessoireSoort_naam ='Kinderzitje' OR aso.AccessoireSoort_naam ='Helm'
      )
```

This one is working but is too complex and I wanna swap it to something like this:

```
    SELECT h.Huurovereenkomst_id, h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
     FROM Huurovereenkomst h
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstAccessoire ha
        ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Huurovereenkomst_id
        INNER JOIN Accessoire a
        ON a.Accessoire_id = ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Accessoire_id
        INNER JOIN AccessoireSoort acs
        ON acs.AccessoireSoort_id = a.Accessoire_Soortnr
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets hf
        ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id = h.Huurovereenkomst_id
    WHERE ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Accessoire_id IN (SELECT  Accessoire_id 
                                                          FROM Accessoire a
                                                          INNER JOIN AccessoireSoort Acs
                                                          ON acs.AccessoireSoort_id = a.Accessoire_Soortnr
                                                          WHERE acs.AccessoireSoort_naam = 'Kinderzitje' OR acs.AccessoireSoort_naam = 'Helm')
    GROUP BY h.Huurovereenkomst_id, h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
    HAVING COUNT(HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id) >= 2
```

But it keeps giving me like a 10% of false results compared to the previous one.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: your column name...lol

Comment: It is not mine haha

Comment: Help us help you.  Explain what you want to do.  Give sample input. Give sample output.  Give table relationship.  Honestly no one is going to look at that query.  Here's a guide.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason you are getting false flags in the second query:  This is most likely because one or both of those tables you join to (`HuurovereenkomstAccessoire` or `Accessoire`) returns multiple rows.  Since joining to it causes multiple rows then `HAVING COUNT(hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id) >= 2` evaluates to true even though it wouldn't have without that join.  For your second query you could make it work by doing `COUNT(DISTINCT hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id) >= 2`

You can also do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.Huurovereenkomst_id, 
    h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,
    h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
FROM
    (
        SELECT h.Huurovereenkomst_id,h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
        FROM Huurovereenkomst AS h
            INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets AS hf ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id
            JOIN Fiets AS f ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id
        GROUP BY h.Huurovereenkomst_id,h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
        HAVING COUNT(hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id) >= 2
    ) h 
    INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstAccessoire as ha ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Huurovereenkomst_id
    INNER JOIN Accessoire as a ON ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Accessoire_id = a.Accessoire_id
WHERE aso.AccessoireSoort_naam ='Kinderzitje' OR aso.AccessoireSoort_naam ='Helm'
```

Not sure which is faster without actually trying it out but both should give you technically correct results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. Precisely the way I meant it!